# Adding control to wfs layer disable panning and zooming on double click

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, wfs

I can zoom and pan wfs layer when I don't have added control but I can't pan the map or zoom the layer with double click when I add a control to map: code for control is :

```
var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(district);
    map.addControl(select);
    select.activate();
    district.events.on({
        featureselected: function(event) {
            feature = event.feature;
            feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored
                    ("dis_pop",
                            feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                            new OpenLayers.Size(285, 250),
                            '<div class="popupcss"><p>' +
                            '<table>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            'Item' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            'Value' +
                            '</td>' 
                            '</tr>' +
                            '</table></div>',
                            null,
                            true
                            );
            map.addPopup(feature.popup);
        },
        featureunselected: function(event) {
            var feature = event.feature;
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            feature.popup = null;
        }
    });
```

The code is working file but I can't zoom on double click. I also can't pan the map with mouse cursor.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what happened anyone with greater knowledge can explain but for anyone with similar problem I solved it by adding controls:

```
// Panel (toolbar)
    var oDragPanCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan({
        isDefault: true,
        title: 'Pan map: keep the left mouse button pressed to drag the map'
    });

var oZoomBoxOutCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({
    out: true, displayClass: "olControlZoomBoxOut",
    title: 'Zoom out: click in the map or use the left '
            + 'mouse button and drag to create a rectangle'
});

var oZoomBoxInCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({
    title: 'Zoom in: click in the map or use the left '
            + 'mouse button and drag to create a rectangle'
});

var oZoomBoxOutCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({
    out: true, displayClass: "olControlZoomBoxOut",
    title: 'Zoom out: click in the map or use the left '
            + 'mouse button and drag to create a rectangle'
});

var oPanel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({
    defaultControl: oDragPanCtrl
});

oPanel.addControls([    
    oZoomBoxInCtrl,
    oZoomBoxOutCtrl,
    oDragPanCtrl
]);
```

map.addControl(oPanel);//map is Openlayers.Map() object

---

You can make this control beautiful by adding css(not required):

```
.olControlPanel div { 
    display:block;
    width:  24px;
    height: 24px;
    float: left; /* remove this if you want a vertical toolbar  */
    margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
}


/* ZoomBox - zoom in */
.olControlPanel .olControlZoomBoxItemInactive { 
    background-image: url("/geoserver/www/openlayers/theme/default/img/zoom_in_off.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.olControlPanel .olControlZoomBoxItemActive { 
    background-image: url("/geoserver/www/openlayers/theme/default/img/zoom_in_on.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

/* ZoomBox - zoom out */
.olControlPanel .olControlZoomBoxOutItemInactive {
    background-image: url("/geoserver/www/openlayers/theme/default/img/zoom_out_off.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.olControlPanel .olControlZoomBoxOutItemActive { 
    background-image: url("/geoserver/www/openlayers/theme/default/img/zoom_out_on.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

/* DragPan */
.olControlPanel .olControlDragPanItemInactive { 
    background-image: url("/geoserver/www/openlayers/theme/default/img/pan_off.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 1px;
}
.olControlPanel .olControlDragPanItemActive { 
    background-image: url("/geoserver/www/Openlayers/theme/default/img/pan_on.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers Documentation says

`featureSelected Listeners will receive an object with a feature property referencing the selected feature.`

so replace

```
featureselected: function(event) {
            feature = event.feature;
```

with

```
featureselected: function(feature){
```

same with `featureunselected`

**UPDATE**
Try this

```
var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(district,{
    onSelect: function(feature) {
            feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored
                    ("dis_pop",
                            feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                            new OpenLayers.Size(285, 250),
                            '<div class="popupcss"><p>' +
                            '<table>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            'Item' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            'Value' +
                            '</td>' 
                            '</tr>' +
                            '</table></div>',
                            null,
                            true
                            );
            map.addPopup(feature.popup);
    },
    onUnselect: function(feature) {
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            feature.popup = null;
        }
    });
map.addControl(select)
select.activate()
```

Comment: I have tried with feature it won't work. With event it will work but only thing is I can't pan and zoom. I can see the popup with all the feature attributes.

Comment: The activating select control activates the event handler o layer. Mayer manually registering event overrode the handlers. See updated answer.

Comment: I couldn't understand?

Comment: i put your event handler inside the control (i.e. featureselected event is handled by the select control's onSelect handler). Replace your code with mine.

Comment: I tried that it didn't work